# Enable edge scrolling under Ubuntu 17.10, with Unity and Compiz

Tags: unity, touchpad, compiz

Several issues with Ubuntu 17.10 running Gnome obliged me to switch back to Unity, having Compiz also enabled.

However, I find no way to enable edge scrolling (on the touchpad) under Ubuntu 17.10, having Unity and Compiz running.

Comment: Natural scrolling and edge scrolling are two different things. Do you want to enable edge scrolling, or do you want to enable natural scrolling for edge scrolling?

Comment: @danzel: I don't know if it is natural scrolling or edge scrolling: I want to scroll the current window up and down using the edge of my touchpad.

Comment: That's edge scrolling.

Comment: When I issue `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i edge-scrolling`, I get twice:
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad edge-scrolling-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad edge-scrolling-enabled true                         ... and still no edge scrolling working.